# TypeScript - Variable implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert an uploaded file's content to an MD5 hash. I'm trying to declare a global declaration to use inside functions. However, when I try to use it, I get the error `Variable 'hasher' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.`

```
  private async hashContentMD5() {
    // Converts content to MD5
    const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
    const hashwasm = require('hash-wasm');

    const chunkSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    let hasher = null;

    function hashChunk(chunk: any) {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        fileReader.onload = async (e: any) => {
          const view = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
          hasher.update(view);
          resolve();
        };

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
      });
    }

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    const readFile = async (file: any) => {
      if (hasher) {
        hasher.init();
      } else {
        hasher = await hashwasm.createMD5();
      }

      const chunkNumber = Math.floor(file.size / chunkSize);

      for (let i = 0; i <= chunkNumber; i++) {
        const chunk = file.slice(
          chunkSize * i,
          Math.min(chunkSize * (i + 1), file.size)
        );
        await hashChunk(chunk);
      }

      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
      const hash = hasher.digest();
      return Promise.resolve(hash);
    };

    // Converts Content MD5 to Base64
    const file = (document.getElementById('fileName')as any).files[0];
    const hash = await readFile(file);
    const promiseArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(hash);
    const content_md5 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(promiseArray);

    return content_md5;
  }
```

How can I define that correctly?

Comment: Although you can define the type explicitly, as explained in the answers, it is also a warning that something may not be right in your code. In this case for example you could easily refactor it to not need a null-initialised variable by passing `hasher` as an argument to `hashChunk()`. It'd also make your code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `tsc` can't determine what `hasher` is supposed to be. This is one of the rare cases where you have to explicitly define its type, like this:

```
let hasher: IHasher? = null;
```

Which tells `tsc` that `hasher` is either an `IHasher` or `undefined` or `null` (make sure to import the `IHasher` type from the `hash-wasm` package first!)